# Operator '+' cannot be applied to operands of type

Tags: c#

I'm having an error. Its saying that the

> '+' operator cannot be applied to operands of type

. the code follows as :

```
Violator.HowManyViolsInMonthRange(dNum, lvsMajors + lvsIntox, 0, 11 >= 2)
```

The error occurs at `lvsMajors + lvsIntox`. They are both `HashSet<int>();` with some constants applied to them.

The auto text prediction format follows as :

```
int(dNum), HashSet<int> violCodeSet (lvsMajors & lvsIntox), minMonth, maxMonth.
```

Thank You

Comment: You can't add two HashSets, so what do you think the expected output of the addition of two hash sets should be?

Comment: HashSets don't support the `+` operator.

Comment: You probably want the Union method of HashSet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `+` operator is not [overloaded](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288467%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) for `HashSet<T>`. But how do you want to add two `HashSet<int>` at all? I can think of at least two ways:

```
lvsMajors.Sum() + lvsIntox.Sum()
```

or

```
lvsMajors.UnionWith(lvsIntox)
```

Comment: lvsMajors.UnionWith(lvsIntox)

Comment: Im sorry. I thought you were asking how I would like to add them.

Answer (score 1):

You can't add two HashSets together. If you want to pass a HashSet containing all elements of both HashSets you could use `lvsMajors.UnionWith(lvsIntox)` but it won't contain any duplicates (i.e. values contained in both `lvsMajors` and `lvsIntox` will only appear once in `lvsMajors.UnionWith(lvsIntox)`.

Comment: That worked to fix the error. However created another error : " the best overloaded method has some invalid arguments.

Comment: (Violator.HowManyViolsInMonthRange(driverNum,lvsMajors.UnionWith(lvsIntox), 0, 11) >= 2)

Comment: @M_B You have an extra ) after 11

Comment: Well since this is the third part of an if (some code) || (some code) ||

Comment: I see 3 open and 3 close.

Comment: Well in your question it seemed that the call you were trying to make is `Violator.HowManyViolsInMonthRange(driverNum,lvsMajors.UnionWith(lvsIntox), 0, 11 >= 2)` (which is essentially the same as `Violator.HowManyViolsInMonthRange(driverNum,lvsMajors.UnionWith(lvsIntox), 0, true)`)

Can you put the function definition for HowManyViolsInMonthRange in your question if you're still having this issue. (The signature SHOULD be of the form `public int HowManyViolsInMonthRange(int, HashSet<int>, int, int)` for this to compile (which does not mean it does what you expect it to do.))